# NEST.js service method for returning JSON from files

Tags: node.js, nestjs, node.js-fs

I am building a simple NEST api, just to learn stuff.
In it there is a service which has a method called 'getTestFileAsJSON'. I am trying to build this api for a blog. There will be articles, which are files in the .txt format.

I am trying to write a method which will read said text files and return JSON as apis should, best on best practices. From what I have read depending on the size of the files ( esp. if they are huge) streams are a good idea.

I was searching around SO for resolutions or more information and finally after several threads decided on writing my method like so:

```
async getTestFileAsJSON() {
    const text = { value: '' };
    const testFileAsReadableStream = createReadStream(
      join(process.cwd(), '/files/test.txt'),
    );

    const streamToString = async (stream) => {
      const chunks = [];
      for await (const chunk of stream) {
        chunks.push(Buffer.from(chunk));
      }
      return Buffer.concat(chunks).toString('utf-8');
    };
    const myText = await streamToString(testFileAsReadableStream);
    console.log(myText);
    text.value = myText;

    return JSON.stringify(text);
}
```

This gets the job done and I get my response. This method is async. But in my controller I do not await it. Does this mean that even thought I have used async/await nothing truly async is happening within the code and so this is why everything is working even though I am not awaiting it in the controller?:

```
  @Get('json-file')
  getStreamFile() {
    return this.blogService.getTestFileAsJSON();
  }
```